# How more Foreign Key works in django

Tags: django

I would like to better understand how ForeignKey works in django, how can I refer `field1` with `barcode` and `field2` with `job`?

```
class User(AuditModel):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default="not_specified", null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=False, blank=False)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=False, blank=False)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.barcode)

class Test_table
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(User,  blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fields1")
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fields2")
```

Thanks

Comment: please don't. You are introducing *data duplication*. It turns out it is hard to keep the fields in sync. If later a user changes their barcode/job, then it will result in a lot of extra logic to keep the `field1` and `field2` in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to_field` parameter.

Like:

```
field1 = models.ForeignKey(User,  blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fields1", to_field="barcode")
field2 = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fields2", to_field="job")
```

But please try to use only one of them. Data duplication is never a good idea.